# Combinate of values in a table to get the sum of each combination

Tags: logic

I have a table with numeric data that i need make diferent combinations itself.
For example:

```
| A | 
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
```

I need to combine this single column to get the next result:

```
| A | B | C | D |
| - | - | - | - |
| 1 |   |   |   |
| 1 | 2 |   |   |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |   |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 |   | 4 |
| 1 |   | 3 |   |
| 1 |   | 3 | 4 |
| 1 |   |   | 4 |
|   | 2 |   |   |
|   | 2 | 3 |   |
|   | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|   | 2 |   | 4 |
|   |   | 3 |   |
|   |   | 3 | 4 |
|   |   |   | 4 |
```

At the end of the table, i have to create a column with the Count of every column that has data and another column that contains the sums of number of each columns.

Maybe it sound very difficult or impossible, but I haven't a way to make it work.

I have try to "Cross Join" from SQL but didn't got the expected result.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can solve this by counting in binary ending with the digits being the number of numbers in the set. etc. the starting set 2568 would end with 1111. this binary number would decide if you show that number in each row. Heres a table of how it would work.
| A |
|---|
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 8 |

| A | B | C | D | Binary | Row number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 8 | 0001 | 1 |
|  |  | 6 |  | 0010 | 2 |
|  |  | 6 | 8 | 0011 | 3 |
|  | 5 |  |  | 0100 | 4 |
|  | 5 |  | 8 | 0101 | 5 |
|  | 5 | 6 |  | 0110 | 6 |
|  | 5 | 6 | 8 | 0111 | 7 |
| 2 |  |  |  | 1000 | 8 |
| 2 |  |  | 8 | 1001 | 9 |
| 2 |  | 6 |  | 1010 | 10 |
| 2 |  | 6 | 8 | 1011 | 11 |
| 2 | 5 |  |  | 1100 | 12 |
| 2 | 5 |  | 8 | 1101 | 13 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 |  | 1110 | 14 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 1111 | 15 |

Comment: That's actually a good way, I didn't think about it. This could also work if I have more than 4, right? Let's say 20 for example.

Comment: Yes, it would because you can always count to more digits in binary.